# Jquery libraries don't work at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make an autocomplete method for a searchfield I have in my MVC application.

It uses Jquery-UI and whenever I link it on of my views, other scripts that don't use the Jquery-UI stop working and I get errors like '.modal' and '.datepicker' isn't a method.

When I comment out the Jquery-UI the datepickers and modals work fine.
Am I doing something wrong with the sequence of adding the libraries? I've tried moving some of them up and in different orders but none seem to work.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Css/profiel_info.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Views/common.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Do you mean that the second bulk of tags is the one you put in some views?

Comment: The last block I put in the main view since it's for a searchbox that's on evry page. The 2nd block I use on pages were there is a date field.

Comment: Probably it's a conflicts between 2 jQuery scripts.. Try to remove the (second bulk) scripts tags one by one and see which exactly cause the problem..

Comment: Tried that, can't get a combination that makes evrything work :D So I thought I was mabye missing something else, hence the question :)

Comment: Not everything, just the modal and the datepicker. This way we will figure it out which of the script tags causing the conflicts then we can think about how to avoid that conflict. (My guess, one of the scripts is including the jQuery script along with its own code).

Comment: I got it to work by replacing: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script> with <script src=//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js></script> Evrything seems to work now, but isn't that a huge downgrade in libraries? Or am I missunderstanding things?

Comment: Glad to hear :) I don't see `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>` in your code though.